# I can't get response from localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, nodemon

I create an app.js and a controller.js it worked before but now i cant get response

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var ctrlElektronik = require('./ElektronikController'); 
app.use('/public',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.get('/elektronik',ctrlElektronik.index);
app.get('/elektronik/bilgisayar',ctrlElektronik.bilgisayar);

app.listen(8000);
```

ElektronikController.js

```
var path = require('path');
module.exports.index = function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'index.html'));
    res.end();
}
module.exports.bilgisayar = function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'login.html'));
    res.end();
}
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "nodedeneme",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "nodemon app.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "^4.17.1"
    }
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1 class="deneme">VS Code</h1>
    <p class="deneme">Hello</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I think maybe the problem in the variable ctrlElektronik in app.js

Comment: so ... when opening `http://localhost:8000/elektronik` you don't get a page with just `VS Code` and `Hello` ??? What error do you see in the browser developer tools console?

Comment: `it worked before` ... before what?

Comment: Can you determine which error you are facing exactly? like you got a blank response or your request timedout or something?

Comment: Ok ok i have solved the problem just now. The problem was in the controller.js

Comment: I wrote there res.end();

Comment: Cuz i couldn't get response from localhost